# Trying to print an array element in front of every row of table in laravel backpack

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I am trying to customize table.blade.php in laravel backpack package and I want to print an array element in front of every row of the table. I am trying something which I am not able to succeed. 
I think [this](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/599) is what I am trying to get.

Let me explain:

1) First I declared my static array above in table.blade.php like this:

```
 <?php
 $array = array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K");

 $items = old($field['name']) ? (old($field['name'])) : (isset($field['value']) ? ($field['value']) : (isset($field['default']) ? ($field['default']) : '' ));
 ?>
```

2) Then in /resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/fields/table.blade.php line 53:

```
@foreach( $field['columns'] as $prop => $label)
  <td>
    <input class="form-control input-sm {{ $prop }}" type="text" ng-model="item.{{ $prop }}">
  </td>
@endforeach
```

I tried to add this: (I know this is the wrong way to do it. The items are repeating with rows again and again):

```
@foreach( $array as $component)
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items" class="array-row">
    <td>
      {{ $component }}
    </td>
    @foreach( $field['columns'] as $prop => $label)
      <td>
        <input class="form-control input-sm {{ $prop }}" type="text" ng-model="item.{{ $prop }}">
      </td>
    @endforeach
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

3) I also tried this: (**THIS IS THE RESULT I WANT** BUT REMOVING  `@foreach( $field['columns'] as $prop => $label)` does not saves the table values so I am failing to achieve my functionality with this view ):

```
@foreach( $body_array as $body_component)
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items" class="array-row">
    <td>
      {{ $body_component }}
    </td>

    <td>
      <input class="form-control input-sm {{ $prop }}" type="text" ng-model="item.{{ $prop }}">
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

4) I added this in my controller:

```
$this->crud->addField([
    'name' => 'NAME',
    'label' => 'LABEL',
    'type' => 'mycustomtable',
    //'entity_singular' => 'option', // used on the "Add X" button
    'columns' => [
        'name' => 'NAME',
    ],
    'max' => 11, // maximum rows allowed in the table
    'min' => 11, // minimum rows allowed in the table
    'tab' => 'TAB1'
], 'update/create/both');
```

I know i am doing wrong in step 2.
Thanks for helping out!!

Comment: Where comes the `items` array in `<tr ng-repeat="item in items" class="array-row">` from?

Comment: see edit in above PHP tag sir I have edited the question